# Boolean not behaving correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, parameters, boolean

I'm making an ajax call to this method

```
def check_solution
    puzzle = Puzzle.find(params[:id])
    solved = puzzle.grid.solution == params[:solution].to_s
    solved_before = params[:solved_before]

    puts !solved_before

    if(solved && !solved_before)
      Puzzle.find(params[:id]).increment!(:times_solved, by =1)
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      response = { :status => "ok", :message => "Success!", :html => solved}
      format.json { render json: response }
    end
  end
```

The parameters going in from my local server are

```
Parameters: {"solution"=>"0001000010110011001100000", "solved_before"=>"false", "id"=>"3758"}
```

Why, when I print out !solved_before with puts, does it say false instead of true?

Comment: there's a big difference between `false` and `"false"`. Which one is yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `solved_before` comes in as a string and not as a boolean.

Comment: @Vigrant cool. You're neither the first, nor last to get tripped up on this one! :D +1 for a well worded/thought out question.